# QGIS Atlas not working in standalone Python script

Tags: pyqgis, atlas

I search to update maps with a standalone Python script on Linux. I use QGIS 3.18.3.
My problem, the beginRender() return false, so there are no atlas element. Anyone have idea?

My code :

```
from qgis.core import *
import qgis.utils
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
import os


folder = "/home/carto/VIGIE/reports/MAPS"

# Supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin", True)

# Create a reference to the QgsApplication.  Setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI.
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

# Load providers
qgs.initQgis()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
project = QgsProject.instance()
data_dir = os.path.join('/home/carto/VIGIE/reports/DW')
project_name = 'DW.qgz'
project_path = os.path.join(data_dir, project_name)

print (project_path)
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge( \
         project.layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
project.read(project_path)

projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()


for comp in projectLayoutManager.printLayouts():
    print(comp.name())
    #image_settings = QgsLayoutExporter(comp.atlas().layout () ).ImageExportSettings()
    image_settings = QgsLayoutExporter(comp.atlas().layout () ).PdfExportSettings()
    image_settings.dpi = 100 # or whatever you want

    att=comp.atlas()
    print(att.enabled())
    print(att.beginRender ())
    print(att.updateFeatures())
    print(att.first ())
    print (att.count ())

    for nb in range(0, att.count ()):
        att.refreshCurrentFeature ()
        (filepath, filename) = os.path.split(folder +'/' + att.currentFilename () +'.pdf')
        if not os.path.exists(filepath): 
            os.makedirs(filepath)
        print(str(nb+1) + ' / ' + str(att.count()) + ' : ' +  filepath+'/'+filename)
        if os.path.isfile(filepath+'/'+filename):
            os.remove(filepath+'/'+filename)
        result = QgsLayoutExporter(att.layout ()).exportToPdf(filepath+'/'+filename, image_settings)
        att.next()
    att.endRender () 



qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: You may look at `beginRender` source code e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/2d1aa68f0d044f2aced7ebeca8d2fa6b754ac970/src/core/layout/qgslayoutatlas.cpp#L373 It returns false if no coverage layer set or no feature found to loop. Try `att.coverageLayer()` . `att.updateFeatures()` seems to not be needed as it's already run within `beginRender`

Comment: Thanks ! Now I know I have an invalid layer. but i d'ont know why.... Perhaps the bridge..

Comment: You layer data source is ? GPKG, shp, csv, PostGIS layer, ...?

Comment: If `att.coverageLayer()` is empty/None, it means you did not set coverage layer (can be normal if not all your layouts are atlas based. Can be tested with `att.atlas().enabled()`). Did you try validity of your layers with something like `[v.isValid() for k, v in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().items()]`?

Comment: Find the problem is the setPrefixPath. I just comment line and it's OK. Thank all. For information there are 4 layers, three postgis and 1 tiles.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your issue.